# C++ Largest Random Number Generator

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate 3 random scores for 3 teams and determine which is the largest. My approach is to use the `Predfined` function, a programmer-defined function, and declare and define the function. I'm very new to this and this book I bought isn't really helping me.

Here are the objective outlines code-side:

- Call predefined functions to generate a sequence of random numbers
- Declare and define a function that returns a value
- Call a programmer-defined function.

The ultimate goal (taken from the book):

- Write a function named `max` that takes three parameters of type `int` and returns the largest value of the parameters. Your program must have both the declaration and definition of this function. The function declaration must be placed above the `main` function.
- Write the function `main()` that does the following:

  a. Generate a random integer between 10 and 40 as the score for each of three teams 
  Hoosier, Boilermakers, and Fighting Irish, and print out these scores. Your program must 
  be able to generate different sequences of scores when it is run at different times.

  b. Call the function `max` defined in Task 1 to find the largest score of all the teams and print out the largest score found.

  c. Compare the largest score to the score of Hoosier, and print out “Go Hoosier!!!” if the Hoosier team’s score equals the largest score of all teams.

Here is the code

```
/*

    Author: Dan Wingeart
    Assignment: Lab 9

*/

#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore);

int main()
{

    int Fscore, Pscore, Hscore, highestScore;

    Fscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
    Pscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
    Hscore = 10 + rand() % 40;

    cout << "Prediction performance of sport teams:" << endl;
    cout << "Team Hoosier's score is " << Hscore << endl;
    cout << "Team Boilermakers' score is " << Pscore << endl;
    cout << "Team Fighting Irish's score is " << Fscore << endl;

    highestScore = max(Hscore, Pscore, Fscore)

    if (max>Pscore&&max>Fscore){
        cout << "The largest score is " << max << endl;
        cout << "GO HOOSIER!!!" << endl;}
    else
        cout << "The largest score is " << max << endl;


return 0;
}

int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore)
{

    if (Hscore>Pscore&&Hscore>Fscore){
        cout << Hscore;}

    else if (Pscore>Hscore&&Pscore>Fscore){
        cout << Pscore;}

    else{
        cout << Fscore;}

return 0;

}
```

The resulting errors:

```
ClCompile:
1>  Lab9.cpp
1>c:\users\mackiller\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab9\lab9\lab9.cpp(34): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'if'
1>c:\users\mackiller\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab9\lab9\lab9.cpp(34): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
1>c:\users\mackiller\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab9\lab9\lab9.cpp(34): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
1>c:\users\mackiller\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab9\lab9\lab9.cpp(35): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>c:\users\mackiller\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab9\lab9\lab9.cpp(38): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1
```

Comment: Tell us why you think you're doing something wrong, don't make us guess. Tell us the expected output, and what output you're getting, along with any error messages (runtime or compile time).

Comment: There are lots of little errors both in syntax and function. Your max function should return the actual max not 0. Missing semicolon on the max function call. Then the "if (max>Pscore&&max>Fscore)" makes no sense..

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - You only tell us that you have a problem, not what kind problem you have... ;-)

Comment: I apologize. I like a function to determine what the higher of these 3 random generated scores and if its hoosier then cheer them on.

Comment: *now you are telling us what you want us to do for you*. **tell us what is failing, exactly and where in the above code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //don't forget to like if the solution is working
    //ask ban

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;

    int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore);

    int main()
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );//(1) 
        int Fscore, Pscore, Hscore, highestScore;

        Fscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
        Pscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
        Hscore = 10 + rand() % 40;

        cout << "Prediction performance of sport teams:" << endl;
        cout << "Team Hoosrand ( time(NULL) );sier's score is " << Hscore << endl;
        cout << "Team Boilermakers' score is " << Pscore << endl;
        cout << "Team Fighting Irish's score is " << Fscore << endl;

        highestScore = max(Hscore, Pscore, Fscore);

        cout<<highestScore;


    return 0;
    }

    int max(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if(a>b && a>c)//we assume that a is the maximum. This means that a > b and a > c
        {
            return a;
        }
        else // if a is not maximum then we assume that b is maximum
        {
            if(b>c)
            {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return c;// if a and b are not maximum then c is maximum
    }
```

//(1)this fct will help you to have different random numbers every time you run the program, more inf here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: It would probably be helpful for the OP if you described what changes you made and why, but this is a correct implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this helped, what i seemed to be doing wrong was that srand  null thing. never heard of that. thank you along with everyone else who helped

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, your max function needs to return an int not always 0. Looks
like you are trying to use cout in the function to print out in the main but 
it doesn't work that way. That causes some of your compile problems.

And you are missing a bracket at the end of the line assigning the results of max 
"highestScore". More compile problems.

Also, you are assigning the result of the max function to "highestScore" but
then never using it. In fact you are using the function "max" by itself which
is probably causing more compiler problems.

Here is my shot at it.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore);

 int main()
 {
     int Fscore, Pscore, Hscore, highestScore;

     srand (time(NULL));  // New numbers each time.
     Fscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
     Pscore = 10 + rand() % 40;
     Hscore = 10 + rand() % 40;

     cout << "Prediction performance of sport teams:" << endl;
     cout << "Team Hoosier's score is " << Hscore << endl;
     cout << "Team Boilermakers' score is " << Pscore << endl;
     cout << "Team Fighting Irish's score is " << Fscore << endl;

     highestScore = max(Hscore, Pscore, Fscore);

     if ( (highestScore>Pscore ) && (highestScore>Fscore) ){
       cout << "The largest score is " << highestScore << endl;
       cout << "GO HOOSIER!!!" << endl;
     } else {
       cout << "The largest score is " << highestScore << endl;
     }

 return 0;
 }

 int max(int a, int b, int c) {
   int m = ( a > b ) ? a : b;
   return  ( m > c ) ? m : c;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your implementation of the `max` function. First you always `return 0` no matter what the `max` is. but there is also another problem.

Lets imagine `Hscore = 40`, `Pscore = 40`, `Fscore = 20` and look at the function.

```
int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore)
{

    if (Hscore>Pscore&&Hscore>Fscore){ // False, Hscore > Pscore is false since Hscore is even but not greater than Pscore
        cout << Hscore;}

    else if (Pscore>Hscore&&Pscore>Fscore){  // False, Pscore > Hscore is false since Pscore is even but not greater than Hscore
        cout << Pscore;}

    else{  // else statement gets executed even tho Fscore was the lowest.
        cout << Fscore;}

    return 0;
}
```

you probably should use `>=` in the max function instead of `>`. It should look like that:

```
int max(int Hscore, int Pscore, int Fscore)
{

    if (Hscore>=Pscore&&Hscore>=Fscore){
        cout << Hscore;
        return Hscore;
    }

    else if (Pscore>=Hscore&&Pscore>=Fscore){
        cout << Pscore;
        return Pscore;
    }

    else{
        cout << Fscore;
        return Fscore;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code sample, I have the impression that the book you have is a little old (it declares all variables at the beginning of the function, which was required in C before 1999).  I would highly recommend you get a newer book.  Personally, I would recommend *Accelerated C++* or *Programming: Principles and Practice using C++* (by the creator of C++).

The biggest problem in your code is the simple fact that the line:

```
if (max>Pscore&&max>Fscore){
```

confuses `max` (a function) and `highestScore` (a variable).  You want that to be:

```
if (highestScore>Pscore&&highestScore>Fscore){
```

Although, personally, I would write it as

```
if (highestScore == Hscore) {
```

Aside from that, you may be interested to discover that the standard library has the functions [`max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) (returns the larger of two items) and [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) (returns the largest item in a sequence) in the `<algorithm>` header.  You could replace your `max` with a call to `max`:

```
int highestScore = std::max(std::max(Hscore, Pscore), Fscore);
```

or a call to `max_element`:

```
int scores[] = { Pscore, Fscore, Hscore };
int highestScore = *max_element(scores, scores + 3);
```